# Mutation Survives When Comparing to Empty String in C++?

Tags: c++, mutation-testing

I am mutating my code and it's complaining that the following mutation survived:

```
--- /home/user/src/file.cc 2019-12-03 13:48:12.510311
+++ /home/user/src/file.cc 2019-12-03 14:00:14.164006
@@ -283,7 +283,7 @@
 }

 bool SomeClass::isValid(proto::SomeProto const& task_pb) const {
-    if (task_pb.task_id() == "") {
+    if (task_pb.task_id() < "") {
         log(LOG_WARNING, "no id given");
         return false;
     } else if (task_pb.task_type() == proto::TaskType::UNKNOWN) {
```

The declaration for `task_id()` is:

```
const ::std::string& task_id() const;
```

Is there a `string` that can be less than `""`?  Would this even be considered a valid mutation for `string`s?

Comment: If `task_id` returns a `const char *`, this is technically valid, but pretty much nonsensical, C++. If `task_id` returns a `std::string`, one of the `<` overloads compares to a `std::string`, and `std::string` can be implicitly constructed from a string literal, so that's what gets compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::string` defines a lexicographic "less-than" relation, that can be accessed [using `operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).

The specific expression you've shown will always evaluate to `false`, because no string sorts (lexicographically) less-than the empty string. But that doesn't make the code invalid, merely pointless. I don't know what you mean by a "valid mutation" exactly, but hopefully that will point you to the answer.

Comment: A "valid mutation" would be a mutation that is actually testable.  Could I come up with a test that provides some value that `task_id()` returns that would pass the existing code but not the mutated code.  It sounds like no.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @StephenRasku The result will be the same for any non-empty `task_id()`, because the conditional assuredly evaluates to `false` in both cases.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: However, the behaviour differs for empty `task_id()`.